# select columns based on range condition with dplyr's select if function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset :

```
 var1 <- c(333, 213, 456)
 var2 <- c(3, 10, 500)
 var3 <- c(356, 813, 856)
 var4 <- c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")
 var5 <- c(589, 111, 989)

dataset <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5)
```

I want to keep columns based on values range : all values of subsetted columns must be between 99 an 1000.

What I tried :

```
library (dplyr)
dataset2 <- dataset %>%
select_if(~.>99 & . <1000)
```

What I want :

dataset2 : var1, var3, var 4

Comment: What about non numerics?

Comment: @NelsonGon I have mix data. I only want to select column based on condition range. I want to drop all other columns.

Comment: Your example keeps var4 but drops var5 for some reason. var4 has factors/characters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also do:

```
dataset %>%
 select_if(~ is.numeric(.) && all(between(., 99, 1000)))

  var1 var3 var5
1  333  356  589
2  213  813  111
3  456  856  989
```

Answer (score 4):

A `dplyr`-`purrr` solution could be:

```
dataset %>%
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
   purrr::keep(~all(.x <=1000))
  var1 var2 var3 var5
1  333    3  356  589
2  213   10  813  111
3  456  500  856  989
```

Answer (score 4):

With base-R's `Filter`:

```r
Filter(function(x) is.numeric(x) && min(x) > 99 && max(x) < 1000, dataset)
#>   var1 var3 var5
#> 1  333  356  589
#> 2  213  813  111
#> 3  456  856  989
```

Answer (score 4):

This is kind of combination of all answers given till now using `purrr`'s `keep` and `discard`

```
purrr::keep(dataset, ~is.numeric(.) && min(.) >= 99 && max(.) <= 1000)

#  var1 var3 var5
#1  333  356  589
#2  213  813  111
#3  456  856  989
```

and with `discard`

```
purrr::discard(dataset, ~!is.numeric(.) || min(.) < 99 || max(.) > 1000)
```