# select columns based on range condition and containing also NA values

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Based on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59599583/select-columns-based-on-range-condition-with-dplyrs-select-if-function)

I have a dataset :
I want to keep columns based on values range : all values of subsetted columns must be between 99 an 1000.

```
 var1 <- c(333, NA, 456)
 var2 <- c(3, 10, 500)
 var3 <- c(356, 813, 856)
 var4 <- c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")
 var5 <- c(NA, 111, 989)

dataset <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5)
```

It works well without NA values

```
dataset %>%
select_if(~ is.numeric(.) && all(between(., 99, 1000)))
```

or

```
purrr::keep(dataset, ~is.numeric(.) && min(.) >= 99 && max(.) <= 1000)
```

but when I introduce NA in my data :

`select_if` function returns me this error :
 "Only strings can be converted to symbols"

`puur::keep` function returns me this error :
"Predicate functions must return a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`, not a missing value"

How can I manage NA ? Select columns based on values range containing alos NA values ?

Comment: Do you need the `NA` values or can delete them? It is a bit hard to compare `NA`s with other values, will return `NA`. One solution I can think of is to recode `NA` as `0`s and then back to `NA`. This is bad because you may have other `0`s .

Comment: @NelsonGon. I want to keep NA. If A reconde NA to 0 they will be out of range...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should solve it

```r
var1 <- c(333, NA, 456)
var2 <- c(3, 10, 500)
var3 <- c(356, 813, 856)
var4 <- c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")
var5 <- c(NA, 111, 989)

dataset <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5)

purrr::keep(dataset, ~is.numeric(.) && min(.,na.rm = TRUE) >= 99 && max(.,na.rm = TRUE) <= 1000)
#>   var1 var3 var5
#> 1  333  356   NA
#> 2   NA  813  111
#> 3  456  856  989
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Since `between` doesn't have `na.rm` parameter, you can modify `select_if` like :

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>% select_if(~ is.numeric(.) && all(between(., 99, 1000) | is.na(.)))

#  var1 var3 var5
#1  333  356   NA
#2   NA  813  111
#3  456  856  989
```

Comment: `select_if(~ is.numeric(.) && all(between(., 10000, 80799), na.rm = TRUE))`works also BUT in my real data I have columns with only NA values and the command keep this columns too !

Comment: @Wilcar yes, `all` has `na.rm` parameter but I think it doesn't select the columns you want ? For columns with all `NA` values, you can do `dataset %>% select_if(~ is.numeric(.) && all(between(., 99, 1000) | is.na(.)) && !all(is.na(.)))`

Comment: Great update ! I was using  `%>%
  select_if(function(x){!all(is.na(x))})`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `findInterval()` from base.

```
dataset[colMeans(sapply(dataset, findInterval, c(99, 1000)), na.rm=T) == 1]
#   var1 var3 var5
# 1  333  356   NA
# 2   NA  813  111
# 3  456  856  989
```